# Zabbix and JMX connection refused

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have Zabbix server and on localhost is running a java-gateway but Zabbix can't check any JMX data becouse it says:

```
cannot connect to [[localhost]:10052]: [111] Connection refused
```

but if I use a Python script from https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/zabbix_get_jmx, I got my values. Here my config:

zabbix-server.conf:

```
JavaGateway=localhost
JavaGatewayPort=10052
StartJavaPollers=5
```

javaGateway.conf:

```
JavaGateway=localhost
LISTEN_PORT=10052
```

From logs I can se if I use Zabbix GUI to check JMX data, nothing happens in java_gateway logs. It looks like it's not able to connect but I don't know why.

Comment: What was your operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by changing `zabbix-server.conf` from:

```
JavaGateway=localhost
```

To:

```
JavaGateway=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Took me a long time to find this. Such a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note that lot of people has similar issues believing that the `zabbix-java-gateway` is running while it's not.

Be sure to have the process running and listening on port `10052`:

```
netstat -anolp | grep :10052
```

If it does not print anything, install the `zabbix-java-gateway` package and start it.

In Debian/Ubuntu-based:

```
sudo apt install zabbix-java-gateway
sudo systemctl start zabbix-java-gateway
```

In Centos:

```
sudo yum install zabbix-java-gateway
sudo systemctl enable --now zabbix-java-gateway
```

Then try again.